# What is this RTS that seems to be based on the real world, with modern military units?

Tags: game-identification

I recently watched some videos by LazerPig on YouTube and in one of them he plays two strategy games that look interesting. One is *Wargame: Red Dragon* but I haven't been able to identify the second one.

It seems to be based on the real world with modern(-ish) military units, It features fighter jets, helicopters, tanks, and infantry units. Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the game]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your screenshot *also* looks like [Wargame: Red Dragon](https://store.steampowered.com/app/251060/Wargame_Red_Dragon/).

A similar video is seen here, with a visually identical map overview seen at the 2:15 mark.

Comment: Oh yeah it really is Wargame: Red Dragon. Funnily enough the map isn't in any of the pictures on their Steam page so I thought it's a completely different game. Thanks a lot!